# Object in Calendar class in java

Tags: java

When we create a object for a class in java we use new keyword but when we create an object for Calendar class we use,

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
```

Why we are not using new keyword here?

Comment: You're calling a static method on `Calendar` which uses the `new` keyword somewhere in its implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendar's constructor is `protected`, which means only classes that extend it can use it's constructor. When you call `Calendar.newInstance()`, it is getting a calendar for your localization through a subclass, `GregorianCalendar` which you can then use.